# Which clause is being modified

Tags: conditional-constructions

I said, “I will go to school today, not if it is snowing, if my cat is awake.”
The meaning is odd, but my question is regarding the grammar of the statement. Does the “if my cat is awake” place a conditional on the main clause “I will go to school today” or does it place a conditional on the conditional “not if it is snowing” or both?